# Current Navigation pasted link breaks

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation

I'm having an issue pasting URLs in a SharePoint site's navigation. When I drop a link into this navigation, the URL will display the link I used (top picture), but when I leave the settings to test the link, it doesn't work because it's been shortened to something unusable (lower picture). I'm aware that adding a link with Browse leaves the user with a link that is suspiciously the same length as the broken link that I end up with. Does anyone know if the link trimming itself is supposed to happen, or is there something broken here?

[image: The URL listed is the one I intend to use]

[image: The URL listed is what's left after SharePoint truncates it]

Comment: This behavior is fine. Its making the URL relative. Are the links working?

Comment: No, the links don't work. I get a 404 error with the shortened link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the link using the following URL format

```
http://soutbendin2.sharepoint.com/sites/kpi/311/lists/311kpimaster/allitems.aspx
```

Note - Please change spelling error in the URL. I typed it by looking into the image.

Comment: The link in that format works. I've noticed that the list settings display exactly that URL, but the page itself has the one I listed as broken. Might you have an idea of the link from the page itself doesn't work?

Comment: Check this http://www.hezser.de/blog/2012/08/18/what-is-the-_layouts15start-aspx-in-sharepoint-2013/